# AutoMapper Map string to OptionSet value in MS Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, automapper, microsoft-dynamics, automapper-2, automapper-3

I am using AutoMapper.
My source object is simple class

```
public class Source
    {

        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string type{ get; set; }
}
```

My destination is a MS **Dynamics CRM** Entity ( I have generated the model using **CrmSvctil**) which contains an **option set** named **type**.

Following is my mapping

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
               .ForMember(dest => dest.type, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.type));
```

I am getting error is type mismatch

Basically  my problem is

**I don't know how to map string to an Option set value using AutoMapper**

Answer (score 0):

OptionSets are stored as OptionSetValues that have a Value Property of type Int, not Strings, hence your type mismatch error.

If your type is an actual int, you just need to parse it:

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
           .ForMember(dest => dest.type, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => new OptionSetValue(int.parse(src.type))));
```

But if it's the actual text value for the option set, you'll need to lookup the text values using the OptionSetMetaData:

```
public OptionMetadataCollection GetOptionSetMetadata(IOrganizationService service, string entityLogicalName, string attributeName)
{
    var attributeRequest = new RetrieveAttributeRequest
    {
        EntityLogicalName = entityLogicalName,
        LogicalName = attributeName,
        RetrieveAsIfPublished = true
    };
    var response = (RetrieveAttributeResponse)service.Execute(attributeRequest);
    return ((EnumAttributeMetadata)response.AttributeMetadata).OptionSet.Options;
}

var data = GetOptionSetMetadata(service, "ENTITYNAME", "ATTRIBUTENAME");
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
           .ForMember(dest => dest.type, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => new OptionSetValue(optionList.First(o => o.Label.UserLocalizedLabel.Label == src.type))));
```